# normal states on a type $III_{\lambda}$ factor

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $M$ be of a type $III_{\lambda}$ factor with separable predual.

If $\lambda=1$, given two normal states $\tau_1$ and $\tau_2$ on $M$.For any $\epsilon>0$, there exists a unitary $u\in M$ such that $\|\tau_1–u\tau_2 u^*\|<\epsilon$.

If $\lambda\neq 1$, does there exist similiar conclusions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paper you are reading is devoted to prove that in a III$_\lambda$-factor $M$
$$
\operatorname{diam}(S_0(M)/\operatorname{Int}(M))=2\,\frac{1-\lambda^{1/2}}{1+\lambda^{1/2}}.
$$
This shows that what you want can only happen in a type III$_1$-factor.

**Edit: why faithful states are enough.** Let $\phi,\psi$ be states, with supports $p$ and $q$. Because we are in a type III factors, $p$ and $q$ are equivalent; in fact, unitarily equivalent. So $q=vpv^*$ for some unitary $v$. Then the state $v\psi v^*$ has support $p$ and is equivalent to $\psi$. This reduces the problem to states with the same support $p$. And these are faithful in $pMp$.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. $S_0(M)$ is the state space of $M$ in that paper and in the formula I wrote.

Comment: What is "norm closed set of its normal states" supposed to mean? In that paper, $S_0(M)$ is the normal state space.

Comment: States are linear functionals. The only meaningful norm I have seen on linear functionals is the usual norm in the dual. As for faithful, a non-faithful normal state can be extended to a normal faithful state; so if the distance can be approximated by some pair of normal states, it can also be approximated by a pair of faithful normal states.

Comment: If $p$ is the support of $\varphi$, take $\psi$ to be a faithful state on $(1-p)M(1-p)$. Then $\varphi+\psi$ is a faithful state.

Comment: In general there is, unless you are dealing with non-separable factors which I would find unusual. In any case, a different argument is possible, I have edited it into the answer.

Comment: Yes. But, like I explain in the edit, it is enough to prove the diameter formula for faithful states in $pMp$.

Comment: You are dealing with type III factors. $pMp$ is **isomorphic** to $M$.

Comment: That's not even well-defined.  In any von Neumann algebra M, if $p∼q$ then $pMp≃qMq$. The isomorphism is $pxp⟼vpxpv^∗$, where $v^∗v=p$, $vv^∗=q$.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean.

Comment: Yes, of course, since $vp=vv^*v=qv$.

Comment: Ah, I was so stupid. THANKS!

Comment: Glad I could help :)